# How to properly configure a custom logrotate configuration file?

Tags: log-files, logrotate, log-rotation

For the first time today, I am trying to write a configuration file for logrotate. When I restart the logrotate service, I get the following error: `logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

If I delete my file and restart logrotate.service, everything is OK

Here is my logrotate.conf configuration file

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Here is my custom configuration file

```
/var/www/webd/logs/clean.log
{
        rotate 12
        monthly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
}
```

What is wrong with this file?

Thanks,

Thierry

Comment: What is your operating system and version? Is logrotate actually configured to run as a service on that system? What does `sudo systemctl status logrotate` (or equivalent on your OS) report? Please edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answer @Tilman Schmidt, I realized that my problem came from a problem of access right to the log file

```
févr. 24 08:34:30 logrotate[23728]: error: skipping "/var/www/webd/logs/clean.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
```

by adding the clause `su webd webd` in my configuration file and by restarting the logrotate service, everything is back to normal

```
/var/www/webd/logs/clean.log
{
        rotate 12
        monthly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        su webd webd
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

theirman